# Discrete Fourier transform of a 2D exponential decay

Tags: dft, fourier, 2d

The Discrete Fourier transform of a 1D discrete decay function $d[n]=e^{-a n}$ is simply computed as the sum of a geometric series: $$\tilde{d}[k] = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}e^{-a n}e^{2 j \pi n k/N} = \frac{1-e^{-a N}}{1-e^{-a -2 j \pi k/N}}$$

However in 2D things seem less obvious to me: is there any closed form for the 2D DFT of $$d[n,p]=e^{-a (n^2+p^2)^{1/2}}?$$  I struggle to see how to sum the DFT series at finite N, or even in the limit $N \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: This would be trivial if you wanted a continuous Fourier transform of that, _and_ you could get away with doing it using polar coordinates centered on the peak.  It would also be trivial if it was rectangular symmetric -- i.e. $d[n, p] = e^{-a\left(|n| + |p|\right)}$.  But if it makes you feel better, I think it'll be a nightmare to do it as expressed.